# Using PHP - How do I combine an anchor tag and a GET variable in the redirect

Tags: php, html, get, anchor

```
I want to combine these:

header("Location: index.php?msg=1");
header("Location: index.php#go-hear");


To look something like this:
header("Location: index.php#go-hear?msg=1");
```

Is this possible?
In other words I am using _GET and sending a case to filter through a switch statement.
But I also want the page to redirect to the bottom of the page using an anchor tag, not the top.

Comment: the anchor goes at the end, after any parsed variables

Comment: oh and headers should be the full URI, not a relative one

Comment: You should also include an `exit;` call after your `header('Location: '.$URL)` otherwise the rest of the PHP is still executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `header("Location: index.php?msg=1#go-hear");`